# Modis LandCover processing

Tags: modis, envi

is there any tool to open and process `MCD12Q1`(modis landcover product)? apparently ENVI doen't work for this. any help highly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

Most packages can handle TIFFs and they're easy to work with.

Use the MODIS Reprojection Tool (MRT) to convert HDFs to TIFFs. You can select the coordinate system and fields you want to extract from the HDF. You can do them one at a time or you can use the tool to create parameter files to mosaic and project multiple scenes for batch processing.

https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool

The MRT tool is a little finicky. You need to have both MRT and Java installed to a folder on your drive without spaces. I suggest reinstalling (or installing) Java and MRT to C:/programs/java and C:/programs/MRT. It can have problems searching for them when they are located in Program Files.

ArcMap can handle HDFs, too.

Comment: thanks, I checked it but didn't work. when opening the file, it gives an error (missing/bad parameters). I checked for many files (hdf5)

Comment: The MRT tool is a little finicky. You need to have both MRT and Java installed to a folder on your drive without spaces. I suggest reinstalling Java and MRT to C:/programs/java and C:/programs/MRT. It can have problems searching for them when they are located in Program Files.

Comment: thanks for the comment, MRT works very well for other modis products (e.g .MOD2khm,Mod10,..), however for mcd12q1 gives an error (missing/bad NBANDA). I'll reinstalling MRT and jave and try again.

Comment: Hm, sounds like it might be corrupt data to me. Is it from reverb?

Comment: download the data from NASA http://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/data/search.html , same errors for all MCD12Q1.

Comment: I'd try downloading the same data on NASA's reverb site. Set spatial and temporal coverage and select the dataset(s) you need. http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/#utf8=%E2%9C%93&spatial_map=satellite&spatial_type=rectangle

Comment: I've used the MCD12Q1 product from NASA Reverb and can confirm that it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is the perfect method to do it.But, if you work with ERDAS, use **import**  and the MODIS file type is **MODIS EOS HDF format**(select from drop down list). you can convert its to another format.Also you can use **gdal** to do it.(in **R** , the package is **gdalUtils**)